# Grok Filter - Parsing with TAB but doesn't work on last field

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

My message is this, with tabs between TO and SUBJECT and MESSAGE but for some reason it fails to parse the last field for MESSAGE:

```
2020-07-20T03:33:01+00:00 webserver.sys.com        TO=admin@test.com SUBJECT=[NOTICE WARNING] NOTICE: Grouping OK on 035750695894      MESSAGE=Log statistics; processed='destination(d_spol)=0', processed='src.internal(s_sys#2)=123012', stamp='src.internal(s_sys#2)=1595217005', processed='destination(d_mlal)=0'
```

I tried to use the grok filter on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ but it fails to parse the last field for 'MESSAGE':

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp8601} %{DATA:host} TO=%{DATA:to} SUBJECT=%{DATA:subject} MESSAGE=%{DATA:msg}
```

Here's the output from https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ where it doesn't match for 'MESSAGE':

```
{
  "timestamp8601": [
    [
      "2020-07-20T03:33:01+00:00"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2020"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "07"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "20"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "03",
      "00"
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "33",
      "00"
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "01"
    ]
  ],
  "ISO8601_TIMEZONE": [
    [
      "+00:00"
    ]
  ],
  "host": [
    [
      "webserver.sys.com       "
    ]
  ],
  "to": [
    [
      "admin@test.com"
    ]
  ],
  "subject": [
    [
      "[NOTICE WARNING] NOTICE: Grouping OK on 035750695894     "
    ]
  ],
  "msg": [
    [
      ""
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the remaining part of the message is parsed for the last field, I can just use GREEDYDATA:

^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp8601} %{DATA:host} TO=%{DATA:to} SUBJECT=%{DATA:subject} MESSAGE=%{GREEDYDATA:msg}